# How to initialize the final variable by Spring @PostConstruct?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have to initialize some final variable,but these value need to be read by Spring Properties

```
public class CrawlerClient{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("crawlerProperties")
    private Properties crawlerProperties;

    private Integer  final maxTopic;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialize();
    }
    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize(){
        List<Topic> topics = topicBusiness.getAll();
        List<Blogger> bloggers = bloggerBusiness.getAll();
        List<Clue> clues = clueBusiness.getAll();
        ClueQueue.addAll(clues);
        TopicQueue.addAll(topics);
        BloggerQueue.addAll(bloggers);

    }
..
}
```

I want to initialize the variable of "maxTopic",but value is in Properties,So I can't do it in construction,how can I do for this?I just know remove the key of "final".
Finally,I do it by this way:

```
final Integer maxTopic;
    final Integer maxBlogger;
    final Integer maxClue;
    @Autowired
    public CrawlerClient(@Qualifier("crawlerProperties")Properties crawlerProperties){
        this.maxTopic = Integer.parseInt(crawlerProperties.getProperty("MaxTopic"));
        this.maxBlogger = Integer.parseInt(crawlerProperties.getProperty("MaxBlogger"));
        this.maxClue = Integer.parseInt(crawlerProperties.getProperty("MaxClue"));
    }
```

Can anyone solve it by the better way?

Comment: Well obviously you cannot as son as the class is constructed the value is final. Why don't you just use the constructor to get the properties injected and do the init there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want with constructor injection:

```
@Component
public class CrawlerClient{
    private Properties crawlerProperties;
    private final Integer maxTopic;

    @Autowired
    public CrawlerClient(@Qualifier("crawlerProperties") Properties crawlerProperties,
         @Value("maxTopic") Integer maxTopic){
        this.crawlerProperties = crawlerProperties;
        this.maxTopic = maxTopic;

        List<Topic> topics = topicBusiness.getAll();
        List<Blogger> bloggers = bloggerBusiness.getAll();
        List<Clue> clues = clueBusiness.getAll();
        ClueQueue.addAll(clues);
        TopicQueue.addAll(topics);
        BloggerQueue.addAll(bloggers);
    }
..
}
```

Comment: Your code won't even compile, unless you change type of "maxTopic" to String and it just equal to Stirng("maxTopic").

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gave me a hint

Comment: I tried to point out idea, how this can be solved. Didn't try to compile it at all.

Comment: So is it solved now? It's not clear to me. I would change my answer based on your clarification edits.

Comment: @luboskrnac How does it work .. Currently getting issue on the same.Can you please help me on it

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha, I haven't seen your code. Your best bet is to create separate SO question + refer to Spring docs around constructs I mentioned here.